# Parsing either JSON or atom+xml response not working (PHP)

Tags: php, xml, json, curl

I am using CURL with an API (OData) that is returning data in either JSON or ATOM+XML (those are the two options with this API that can be set in the CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER setting). Here is my code:

```
$url = "https://www.mywebsite.com/4.3/TableExample()?".'$filter'."=(IDNumber%20eq%20'115735')%20and%20(StatusID%20eq%202)%20and%20(AnotherID%20eq%207)%20and%20(IDDate%20ge%20datetime'2012-10-24T00:00:00')%20and%20(IDDate%20le%20datetime'2015-10-26T00:00:00')".'&$expand'."=Items";

$curlConn = curl_init($url); 
curl_setopt($curlConn,CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER,array('Accept: application/atom+xml')); 

//OR FOR JSON
//curl_setopt($curlConn,CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER,array('Accept: application/json')); 

$ret = curl_exec($curlConn); 
curl_close($curlConn);
```

This works fine (and in fact this code alone displays the response info in the browser without having to echo, etc.).

When I get the atom+xml returned, it returns it in the browser likes this:

```
<!--?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" standalone="yes"?-->
<html>
    <head></head>
    <body>
        <feed xml:base="http://www.mywebsite.com/4.3/" xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2007/08/dataservices" xmlns:m="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2007/08/dataservices/metadata" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom">
            <title type="text">TableExample</title>
            <id>http://www.mywebsite.com/4.3/TableExample</id>
            <updated>2014-05-30T18:37:34Z</updated>
            <entry>
                 <!--DATA RETURNED HERE-->
            </entry>
```

And then the closing tags. It's strange because it's not fully XML and it's not fully HTML. Also when I try to parse it used SimpleXMLElement it doesn't find anything. I've also tried simplexml_load_string and that doesn't work. When I received it as JSON, it looks like normal JSON code but again is wrapped in HTML tags so I'm assuming that's what json_decode doesn't work on the element.

Any ideas why I can't parse any of this data?

Comment: When you use `simplxml_load_string` do you see any errors in the log?  What happens when you do use print_r on the resulting object?  i.e. `$x = simplexml_load_string($atomstring); print_r($x);`

Comment: HI @Robbert, when I do that I get an error: `Warning: simplexml_load_string() [function.simplexml-load-string]: Entity: line 1: parser error : Start tag expected, '<' not found in` and then the file and line number info...

Comment: Are the feeds something you created?  It's odd that the JSON code is wrapped in html tags.  That shouldn't be happening.  If you created the feeds, I would look at your code there to ensure you're sending properly encoded JSON and XML.

Comment: No, I don't create the feeds. I'm just pulling them from an API that I send parameters to.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to make this work by adding the CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER value to the request:

```
curl_setopt($curlConn,CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER,1);
```

With a JSON header, I used json_decode and it made it an array. And with atom+xml in the header, I used new SimpleXMLElement() to convert it to an array.